# position: sticky; not working inside router-outlet child components

Tags: css, angular, parent-child

I am unable to use sticky position on elements that are found inside child components. position fixed works but doesn't resolve the desired design overall.

Using css

```
.sticky{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Using the css property on the parent element works just fine.

Also the feature for Mat Table Sticky Headers has a similar issue where the headers don't apply sticky property when inside router-outlet child component

Please find the code here
https://github.com/shakyamoksha/research-app/tree/master/src/app/components/sticky-table/components

The Component is found in the router outlet, if i move the same code to the root/parent component ( app.component.html), the sticky will work.

Same issue happens when trying to add the css above to a simple button found inside the router-outlet

```
    <div class="mat-app-background basic-container">
  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

      <!-- Position Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Weight Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Symbol Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

The style

```
.basic-container {
  padding: 30px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

On scroll, the header of the mat-table is stuck to the top
Expected Behaviour has in this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brzwrz-aejes6?file=src%2Findex.html

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add your code as a (minimal working) snippet so we can take a look.

Comment: Hi thanks Fabian. Please find the code here 

https://github.com/shakyamoksha/research-app/blob/master/src/app/components/sticky-table/components/sticky-table.component.html

The Component is found in the router outlet, if i move the same code to the root/parent component ( app.component.html, the sticky will work. Same issue happens when trying to add the css to a simple button found inside the router-outlet

Comment: Post all relevant, minimal code that's needed to reproduce your problem, here and don't just link to your github.

Comment: Hello, i have posted all the relevant code to it necessary to reproduce the problem